# 3 camadas vs MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, arquitetura-de-software, engenharia-de-software

3 camadas:

- DAL (Onde fica as classes (model) e as operações com o banco
- BLL (Onde fica a regra de negócio)
- Apresentação (Geralmente a WEB)

Um exemplo:

DAL

```
public class AlunoBanco
{
    public void InserirAluno(Aluno aluno){
        ...
        "INSERT INTO ALUNO (aluno)"
        ....
    }
}

public class Aluno
{
    public string ra {get;set;}
    public string nome {get;set;}
}
```

BLL

```
public void InserirAluno(Aluno aluno){
    DAL.InserirAluno(aluno);
}
```

Apresentação

```
protected void Salvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var aluno = new Aluno();
    aluno.ra = ra.Text;
    aluno.nome = nome.Text;
    BLL.InserirAluno(aluno);
}
```

**Seria isso um projeto de 3 camadas?**

**Posso considerar que em um projeto MVC, a única diferença seja a troca da BLL por um Controller?**

**MVC**

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Aluno aluno)
{
    DAL.InserirAluno(aluno);
    return View();
}
```

**Então qual é a diferença entre MVC e 3 camadas?**

Posso considerar esse projeto como 3 camadas?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Seria isso um projeto de 3 camadas?

Sim, você definiu 3 camadas: dados, negócio e apresentação.

## Posso considerar que em um projeto MVC, a única diferença seja a troca da BLL por um Controller?

Não. É comum pensarem isso, mas vai um pouco mais além.

Em primeiro lugar, é preciso ver as coisas do ponto de vista de um *Model*. Um *Model* é uma classe que define não apenas os elementos de dados, mas quais valores eles podem receber, como são validados e as relações de um *Model* com outro, coisa que não existe no Modelo de 3 Camadas.

No 3 Camadas, você precisa colocar validações, relações e características de cada entidade  ou na camada de dados, ou na camada de negócio.

Um exemplo de *Model*:

```cs
public class Product
{
    [Key] // Aqui uso um atributo para definir que a propriedade a seguir é chave.
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Nome é obrigatório.")] // Aqui defini que o campo não pode ser vazio, juntamente com a mensagem de erro que deve ser exibida caso a validação falhe.
    public String Name { get; set; }

    // Aqui defini que um produto pertence a uma, e apenas uma categoria.
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    // Aqui defini que um produto pertence a várias compras.
    public virtual ICollection<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }
}
```

Em segundo lugar, a responsabilidade de um *Controller* é a de harmonizar e arbitrar as relações entre *Models*. É ele que comanda a criação, modificação, exclusão e seleção dos dados da aplicação. Além disso, é ele que recebe a requisição e decide o que deve ser retornado como apresentação, como por exemplo o formato dos dados (HTML, JSON, e assim por diante).

Há abordagens que procuram colocar uma camada extra para trabalhar juntamente com o *Controller*, sob a alegação de que não é responsabilidade do *Controller* de cuidar de regras de negócio. Isto não é verdadeiro se for considerado como aspecto algo que ele é responsável por fazer, no caso, a harmonização de dados entre *Models*. Em um projeto que use Entity Framework, isto:

```cs
var user = context.Users.Find(userId);
var profile = new Profile { User = user };

context.Profiles.Add(profile);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Ou seja, a criação de um objeto, a atribuição de uma informação ao objeto e o comando de passar o objeto a um contexto de dados faz parte da harmonização entre *Models*, mas é regra de negócio.

## Posso considerar este projeto como 3 camadas?

[image: Exemplo]

Grosso modo, sim. O que você fez foi inserir uma camada de "Modelo" (que não é bem "Modelo", mas sim uma camada de Domínio, que é outro conceito). Esta camada "Modelo" pode sim ser vista pela apresentação porque é só uma informação de como serão os objetos de transferência de dados que a aplicação irá usar. É como se fosse um contrato pré-estabelecido entre as 3 camadas. Não havendo regras de negócio nem comportamentos peculiares, vocês apenas estaria [seguindo o padrão DDD](http://www.agileandart.com/2010/07/16/ddd-introducao-a-domain-driven-design/).

Comment: No meu exemplo defino a classe alunos, na camada de dados. Então na camada de apresentação utilizo essa classe. Isto está errado não? Pois a camada de apresentação não pode ter comunicação com a de dados, certo?

Comment: Não entendi. Estou me referindo ao 3 camadas.

Comment: Vejo em alguns exemplos na internet, utilizarem uma camada chamada DTO.

Comment: Falei bobagem. Deixa eu comentar de novo.

Comment: Então, se você quer usar o objeto de Aluno na apresentação, precisa definir uma 4a camada chamada Domínio, contendo a representação de cada DTO, em outra DLL em separado.

Comment: Mas pelo **3 camadas**, eu não posso utilizar o Aluno na apresentação?

Comment: Sim, pode. Como eu disse, se estiver numa DLL em separado das outras 3 camadas.

Comment: Imaginando que tenho um select que traga todos os alunos, uma List<Aluno>, como a camada de apresentação trata isso, sendo que ela não "conhece" Aluno?

Comment: Adicionei uma imagem na pergunta...

Comment: @Felipe Vou complementar a resposta com essa sua imagem.