# Como usar AJAX em muitas Camadas?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, aplicação-web

Estou Estudando DDD Tenho uma aplicação com 4 camadas sendo elas

- Apresentação
- Aplicação
- Domínio
- Infra

Na camada de apresentação busco dados via Ajax No DB, mas tenho uma duvida quanto a forma de fazer. Eu preciso fazer o ajax passar por todas as as camadas ? O que tenho percebido uma perda de performance na aplicação... Caso não, qual a melhor forma pra fazer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A maioria das vezes não é necessário, e nem recomendado usar essa arquitetura com      [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc). Pelo contrário. Muitas vezes você está apenas complicando uma coisa simples, sem necessidade. Isso já foi comentado aqui algumas vezes, como nas perguntas/respostas abaixo:

- [Quando usar Entity Framework com Repository Pattern?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80696/20615)
- [Entity Framework DDD Infra repositório Genérico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40585/20615)
- [3 camadas vs MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33354/20615)
- [Como implementar o Padrão Repository no C# com EF?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16127/20615)

Mas, se mesmo assim você ainda quiser continuar com essa estrutura, você deve fazer exatamente dessa forma.

A requisição `Ajax` chamará uma Action em seu controller e ele passará os dados para as demais camadas.

Com relação a perca de performance, provavelmente não é somente a estrutura, e sim algo em seu código.

Comment: Para indicar uma forma mas performática, existe inúmeras formas, mas para isso é necessário saber o seu contexto ou como está fazendo, para verificar onde "possui erros".