# Os paradigmas MVC e Webforms (com code-behind) são mutuamente excludentes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net

A minha dúvida decorre da explicação de um instrutor que aformou que o padrão MVC se aplicaria à camada de apresentação, mas ao me deparar com [esta outra dúvida e respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33352/3-camadas-vs-mvc?newreg=66ecb86cedeb4e2c814dadc79a68c6bf) passei a crer que ou se opta pelas camadas Model-View-Control ou pelas camadas Web-BLL-DAL com a camada Model (ou DTO) fazendo um link entre as mesmas.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la agora? Veja o [tour] para entender como funciona. Ajudaria muito indicar para todo mundo que a solução foi útil e satisfatória para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

MVC e WebForms são padrões de projeto ou padrões arquiteturais como consideram alguns (há controvérsias), mas não são paradigmas.

3 Camadas nada tem a ver com isso. É um termo genérico demais para definir alguma coisa. É possível aplicar essas três camadas específicas mostradas na pergunta referenciada com MVC, com WebForms e com inúmeras outras formas. Isso é ortogonal. Mas não faz sentido.

Em tese [é possível usar MVC e WebForms juntos](https://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/one-aspnet-integrating-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-and-web-api?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Não faz muito sentido, só ocorreria em um sistema legado que está fazendo a transição para o outro padrão. Ou o programador não tem noção do que está fazendo. Não é lá muito fácil fazer funcionar direito, mas é possível. No fundo haverá uma integração entre as partes mais do que ser uma coisa só. Tecnicamente eles não são excludentes, mas na prática acabam sendo.

A pergunta e resposta referenciada mostra que DAL e BLL costumam ser mescladas no MVC. E *Controller* e *View* são fortemente integrados no WebForms (bom, isso não mostra tão claramente, mas é assim).

No MVC as regras de negócio ficam no *Model*. Se alguém separar a sua estrutura de dados e as regras estará criando duas camadas para o *Model*. Há quem defenda isso, há quem ache abominável.

O *Controller* lida com o fluxo da aplicação. Algumas pessoas consideram que as regras de aplicação que vão além do fluxo devem ser separadas em outra camada de serviço. Outras acham abominável. Algumas pessoas colocam regras de negócio aqui. Há quem ache isso muito estranho.

A *View* do MVC funciona de forma muito mais desacoplada que o equivalente do WebForms. Neste último é possível encontrar regras da aplicação e até de negócios (via *code-behind*), principalmente quando o programador está perdido.

Para tudo existe vantagens e desvantagens. Quem segue regra fixa e diz "isso pode ou não pode", já começou errado. Tem algumas coisas que raramente são vantajosas, claro, mas tem que entender com profundidade o que está fazendo, as consequências de todas decisões, assim a decisão será mais correta, que é a única coisa que importa. Atender regrinhas impostas por terceiros não ajuda em nada.

Lembre-se que WebForms é totalmente legado, e mesmo [o ASP.NET clássico já não deve mais ser usado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101) em projetos novos, vá para o ASP.NET Core.