# desenvolvimento em camadas c# (BBL,DAL,Modelo, GUI)

Tags: c#, winforms

Em meu projeto estou desenvolvendo em C# usando windows Form Application com o padrão de desenvolvimento em Camadas estou com dúvida se essa forma está correta? pois já pesquisei um monte sobre camadas, mas percebo que cada uma pessoa desenvolve de um jeito.

Possua as seguintes camadas:

- BBL - regras de negócios ou validações;
- DAL - para acesso ao banco
- GUI - para os formulários e parte de interação com usuário
- Modelo - onde fica os modelos de classe para herança.

Para gravar um usuário estou desenvolvendo dessa forma:

**DAL - Conexão:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.Data;
using Npgsql;

namespace DAL
{
    public class Conexao
    {
        protected NpgsqlConnection Con; // estabele a conexao
        protected NpgsqlCommand Cmd; // executar e escrever os comandos sql
        protected NpgsqlDataReader Dr; //retorna os registro das querys das consultar
        // Dados da conexao 
        private string servidor = "127.0.0.1";   
        private string porta = "5432";
        private string userBD = "postgres";
        private string senhaBD = "123";
        private string banco = "teste";
        private string connString = null;

        protected void abrirConexao()
        {

            try
            {
                connString = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};",
                                                servidor, porta, userBD, senhaBD, banco);
                Con = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
                Con.Open();

            }
            catch (NpgsqlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("erro ao abrir conexao" + ex.Message);
                throw new NpgsqlException(ex.Message);

            }
        }

        protected void fecharConexao()
        {
            try
            {
                Con.Close();
            }
            catch (NpgsqlException ex)
            {

                throw new NpgsqlException(ex.Message);
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

**DAL - UsuarioDAL**

```
namespace DAL
{
    public class UsuarioDAL : Conexao
    {
        public void insere(UsuarioModel usuario) 
        {
            try
            {
                //Abre a conexao para insercao
                abrirConexao();
                Cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into \"Cadastro\".\"Usuario\" (id) values (@id)", Con);
                Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", usuario.id);
                Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Usuario Inserido com Sucesso");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro ao inserer usuario - Erro: " + ex.Message);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Modelo - Usuario modelo**

> só get e set e construtor ...

Agora no pacote **BBL - UsuarioBBL** devo fazer as validaçoes ? criar o metodo ValidarInsercao e validar com **Data Annotations** e chamar o insere do **DAL**?

e na classe UsuarioGUI devo somente instanciar o UsuarioBBL para ficar mais seguro e executar o ValidaInsercao?

Seria essas minhas dúvidas que impedem que eu desenvolva em c#.

Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos.

Comment: E a minha opinião é que quase todo mundo faz erado, mas como é só opinião, pra eu mostrar todo o problema que fazem eu levaria muito tempo, seria quase um livro, e que o que eu penso é um pouco controverso, afinal todo mundo faz de outro jeito, nem vou tentar responder. Muito provavelmente alguém dará uma opinião e você terá que decidir se segue ou não.

Comment: Na GUI vc vai precisar popular seu modelo, não sei dizer se é a melhor forma, mas se eu estivesse no seu lugar eu ia ler mais a respeito do [desenvolvimento baseado em camadas](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/259840).

Comment: [Aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33354/27190) tem mais informações do desenvolvimento baseado em camadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não dá pra seguir à risca.

Eu programo há 29 anos e há alguns anos, com a mesclagem desktop/web, percebi vantagem em dividir nas camadas:

- **DADOS** - Sem comentários. É como você já faz. (clsDados...)
- **VIEW** (view_web/view_desktop/view_mobile)  - Aqui é onde a equipe separa a camada de apresentação. (Windows Forms)
- **MODEL** - As demais classes (clsEmpresa, clsNotaFiscal...)
- **CONTROL** - Validações, funções de Formatação, etc. (clsFuncoes, ...)

Pense em um modelo de programação DESACOPLADO, onde não haja dependência entre uma camada e outra.

Exemplo1: Evite estar na camada CONTROL e de lá, fazer referência a objetos da camada VIEW:

```
public static void fRetiraAcentuacao(string texto)
{ 
   form2.txtCNPJ.Text = texto.Replace()... ; 
}
```

Acho mais elegante e desacoplado assim:

```
public static void fRetiraAcentuacao(string texto, ref TextBox txt)
{ 
   txt.Text = texto.Replace()... ; 
}
```

Exemplo2: Não posso estar em form1 e chamar:

```
**form2**.TextBox.Text = string.Empty;
```

É como faço e ajuda na programação dentro de times de desenvolvimento.

Outra coisa: lembre-se sempre que outro programador precisa dar manutenção no seu código. Comente o que não é óbvio.

Ansioso para ver como outros fazem!

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Diego. Então, eu devo criar um classe UsuarioModelo com os get e set constutor... Depois criar uma classe UsuarioControl que ira fazer por exemplo as validações de dados, por exemplo InserirUsuario, ele que vai validar a informação e chamar a classe UsuarioDAO? 
E usar o InserirUsuario dentro da view? para ficar melhor?

Comment: Isso! Esse livro é antigo, mas trata o desenvolvimento em três camadas: https://goo.gl/7jL4xx